# PHP PEAR Mail Error

Tags: php, smtp, pear

I'm getting an error with the following code when trying to send an email. It works on my local machine but not when I put it on my AWS LAMP server.  I cannot debug anything because I'm getting an HTTP 500 error when I run the script.  However, I know PEAR is installed.

Code:

```
require_once "Mail.php";

$from = "Email<Test@example.com>";
$to = "steve@exmaple.com";
$subject = "ERROR REPORT";
$body = "test message";

$host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$port = "465";
$username = "test@gmail.com";
$password = "pass1";

$headers = array ('From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
array ('host' => $host,
    'port' => $port,
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password));


$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);


if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
    } else {
    echo("Error message sent!");
}
```

It appears to be bugging out at the send() command above. Any suggestions on how to better debug this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following two lines:

```
ini_set('display_errors','on');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Placing those two early in the script bypasses the php.ini settings that would hide the errors otherwise. Hope that helps!

Also, if you can, place them in the PHP file that gets called and then include the file that uses the mail functions. That way, you avoid the code above not working due to a syntax error.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Problem was I didn't have Net_SMTP installed

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the web server's error log, i.e. `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.